# SPARQL query on Protege for Number of Classes

Tags: sparql, protege4

In order to determine the number of classes in a `.owl` file,

I was advised to use the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ( count(?class) as ?count )
    WHERE { graph <put_your_model_graph_name_here> { ?class a owl:Class . } }
```

However, when I replace the `put_your_model_graph_name_here` with my ontology IRI, I get `0`

I also tried `http://blahblahblah` followed immediately by `#` to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to tell without seeing how you are loading and querying the data. Try using:

```
SELECT ( count(?class) as ?count ) { ?class a owl:Class }
```

which will query the default graph, or

```
SELECT ?g ( count(?class) as ?count ) 
{ graph ?g { ?class a owl:Class } }
group by ?g
```

which will give counts for all the named graphs.

Comment: Thank you! The first one returns what I'm after. I literally open an OWL file in Protege. That's how I 'load' my query data... Cheers

Comment: In that case you'll never need `graph ... { }` in your queries.